Unable to add id in URL request through req params
I want to retrieve product by id from server in mongoose but req.params.id is not working.
I replaced req.params.id with id number to see if there is any other problem but it worked fine.
Here is the code
router.route("/:id").get(getProductById);
const getProductById = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
  if (product) {
    return res.json(product);
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("Resource not found");
  }
});


I wanted to get product by id but req.params.id is not doing anything.

Hi, Please check what is in req.params.id using a console.log as the first line of statement in the handler.
